# Draw square behind text?

Tags: android, layout

[my layout http://img861.imageshack.us/img861/9107/squarebehindtext.png](http://img861.imageshack.us/img861/9107/squarebehindtext.png)

As you can see the square is awesome, but my text at the bottom (barely visible) is draw AFTER the square, and not ontop of the square as I would like. Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/abslayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/dragon"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/banner3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/playerInfoSquare" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        android:text="Player Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerHealth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Heatlth : 0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerMana"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Mana : 0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Whats the best way to draw those TextViews ontop of my beautiful square?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with FrameLayout.

```
<FrameLayout >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="172dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.09"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/playerInfoSquare" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/playerHealth"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Heatlth : 0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Relative layout instead of linear and aligning it to bottom of parent.
or there is another way ..go through [this:](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)